# Mesh goes dark blue after applying auto smooth, happens when i flip normals

Tags: modeling

Basically i need to flip normals to add solidify modifier(or else it solidifies outside when I need it to solidify inside of the mesh(car fender panel).

But when I do, the mesh of the fender panel changes color to darker blue when I apply or keep autosmooth enabled....

I have gotten this usually bypassed by unenabling autosmooth, doing what I need and reapplying autosmooth when I am done, but this tactic dosent work whit Flip normals....

[image]
[image]

Will this affect my model when I am done whit it and exported to .dae?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to **Flip Normal Directions**, you can just adjust **Offset** in **Solidify** modifier tab. This method will allow you too choose which side you want to "extrude" or you can even have it in the middle (0 value).

Also you can check **Flip Normals** in **Solidify** modifier options, if you by mistake have flipped normals - this one will help you to make them right.

[image]